# how to get value of specifice tag element from user defined class in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the value of `b` tag using jquery from `class="address"`. Is there any way to do that.

```
<div class="address"> 

    <h4>Your Restaurant address is:</h4>      
    <p style="font-size:10px"><b>BANSHANKARI</b><br />NO-17, GF, 3RD PHASE, NEAR BIG BAZAR, 100FT RING ROAD, 6TH BLOCK, BANASHANKRI III STAGE, BANASHANKRI,BANGALORE - 560085 PH.NO. 080-26699595/ 26699540 / 45/ 41723004/3020<br />Phone: 8026699595</p>`   

</div>
```

Comment: you can either do `$('p').html()` or it is better to assign a class or id to the p as <p class='test'>...</p> and do `$('p.test').html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the innerText of an element.

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

```
$('.address b').text();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8qsue0sz/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this :

```
$('b').text();
```

or

```
$('p b').text();
```

Happy Coding :)